# Selected = true stops working when Value field is different from Text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var option = cod.Select(coursesDetail => coursesDetail.Course_Date == c ?
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = coursesDetail.Course_Date,
    Value = coursesDetail.Course_Date,
    Selected = true
}:
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = coursesDetail.Course_Date,
    Value = coursesDetail.Course_Date
}).ToList();
```

I am passing a list to my view , the code above works perfectly fine and selects an option by default if the conditions are met. However, if I make the following change:

```
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = coursesDetail.Course_Date,
    Value = coursesDetail.Course_Desc_ID.ToString(),
    Selected = true
}:
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = coursesDetail.Course_Date,
    Value = coursesDetail.Course_Desc_ID.ToString()
}).ToList();
```

where Course_Desc_ID is an id , selected = true stops working.
Where am I making a mistake ?

Comment: What is the error you have ? When it stops, could you paste the error? And put a breakpoint at `Value` to see if it retrieves the string.

Comment: it gives no error , but selected = true does not work even
it generates a list with no selected value by default

Comment: It's most likely due to the fact that `Value` no longer matches `Text`  - it's not a mistake from you, it's more likely due to how MVC renders the select list. It probably attempts to set the selected item based on the value (which in this case won't match the text) so it doesn't work. You may have to resort to setting the selected item manually on the list rather than relying on the `Selected` property.

Comment: Another thing what happens if you have 2 records meeting the condition in your where clause  and you use SelectList instead of a MultiSelectList?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed something else in your code (i.e. are you *sure* there is a `Selected` item in the list)?

Comment: Adding on to @MichaelPerrenoud - are you sure your `if` statement is returning `true` ?

Comment: the only thing that i have changed is the Value field , as mentioned above

Comment: if statement is working fine too , i checked it by debugging